# Need help to complete VBA date/color code

Tags: vba, date, colors

I am working on a vba code to do the following:

In row 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, and 21 from column D until M. Check the value in these cells (which is a date). If the date is 3 months before the date of today turns the cell yellow. If the date is one month before the date of today turn the cell orange. If the date in the cell is today or has passed turn the cell red.

I have the following only the range needs to be adjusted:

```
Sub ChangeColor()

Dim rCell As Range

With Sheet1

    For Each rCell In .Range("D4")
        If rCell.Value <= Date Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            ElseIf rCell.Value <= Date + 30 Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbOrange
        ElseIf rCell.Value <= Date + 90 Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next rCell
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Dim rCell As Range

With Sheet1

    For Each rCell In .Range("D5:M21") ' Change the Range
        If rCell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then ' Only odd rows
            If rCell.Value <= Date Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                ElseIf rCell.Value <= Date + 30 Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 150, 0) ' vbOrange isn't a thing
            ElseIf rCell.Value <= Date + 90 Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell
End With
```

Comment: Thank you this helped i added:  'If rCell.Value <> "" Then' to only apply it to cells that have a value